# Can someone please help identify this euphorbia?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I purchased this euphorbia a few days ago and would very much appreciate an ID on it. It is in a 6" pot

[image]

here is a close-up for more detail
[Close-up http://selva.cabal.mx/Pic.jpg](http://selva.cabal.mx/Pic.jpg)

From the top
[Close-up http://selva.cabal.mx/Pic2.jpg](http://selva.cabal.mx/Pic2.jpg)

It does exude sap when pricked
[Close-up http://selva.cabal.mx/Pic3.jpg](http://selva.cabal.mx/Pic3.jpg)

Comment: Any idea which euphorbia it might be?

Comment: Not off hand. I'd have to look at some literature but I'm out of town. I think someone will nail the ID on this shortly.

Comment: Hard to see detail - are the spines reddish in colour, especially towards the top? Is there a small tuft of spines at the top of each column?

Comment: I guess that I can't add a photo with comments

Comment: And that sap does look exactly like Euphorbia sap - don't get it on your skin!

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm torn between Cereus validus and Euphorbia virosa, but because of the white  'knotting' up the ridges on the stems, and its less than perfectly straight cylindrical growth, I'll go with Euphorbia virosa http://www.learn2grow.com/plants/euphorbia-virosa. This plant sometimes spirals as it grows, but more often doesn't - be aware though that it has very caustic sap.

UPDATE:

Oh good, someone else (on another site) has suggested Euphorbia polycantha, and now I've seen it, I concur completely, looks almost exactly like yours - whoever ID'd it should get votes!

Comment: I was leaning towrds E. Pentagona, but your id of E. Virosa fits the bill better. Thank you

Comment: Can you scratch or prick the plant lightly to see whether it exudes the telltale sap of all Euphorbias?

Comment: I added a Photo of the plant taken from the top as well as the results of pricking it. It does exude a sap as you can see from the photo.

Comment: Someon on Walter Reeves suggested e. polyacantha as an id. What do you think?